# Flipped Parabola in C++

Tags: c++, math

I'm programming a game requiring evaluation of the function y = -x^2+49. When I type the following to my TI-84, I have to type it -(x)^2 + 49 or -x^2 + 49, and NOT (-x)^2 + 49. And here's how I implemented it in C++

```
pp[i].death = -(j)^2 + 49;  // Upside down hyperbola
```

I put a breakpoint to track the value, and it just doesn't makes sense.  My j is in the range [-7, +7] so it should return results in the range [0, 49].  But the C++ code gives me 52 or some random number that's way off. Answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`^` is the [bitwise xor operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR), not exponentiation.

Use `std::pow` instead.

Comment: Which also means he is using integers which is most likely wrong as well.

Comment: I can accomodate that with static_cast<int>(-pow(j,2)). not that dumb lol, I just need some serious reference poster.

Comment: Better yet, just use -j*j + 49. pow takes a lot longer.

Comment: @phkahler Yeah definitely, although ideally you'd want to use an integer exponent function.